# Serving QR images through asp.net api that excel could retrieve it

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, vba, image

I've have a need to insert pictures in excel, generated by a web api
Been using so far this public available api:

```
sURL = "https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=300x300&data=" + QR_Value
Dim myPicture As Picture
Set myPicture = sheet.Pictures.Insert(sURL)
```

But now i need to have my own on my local network.
So i created one with ASP.NET CORE 6.0 on IIS server.

But the problem is that excel could not get this image, even it is possible to see it through the browser.

The difference between this public option that works an mine is that response headers are a bit different.

not working:

[image]

working:

[image]

I tried to enable cors:

```
string allowSpecificOrigins = "CorsPolicy";

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(allowSpecificOrigins,
        builder => builder
            .AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader());
});

...
app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors(allowSpecificOrigins);

app.UseAuthorization();
```

but it has no effect on headers.

Maybe someone has dealth with same problems before and have a solution?

Comment: You say Excel could not get this image, but you don't tell us how it fails. Does an exception get thrown? Do you see any sort of error? What actually happens?

Comment: Exactly how is the image returned from your new service?

Comment: I get Run-time error '1004': Unable to get the Insert property of the Pictures class.

And my image is returned this way:
Controller has these attributes"
```
[HttpGet]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK, Type = typeof(Image))]
```
and return is byte[]
```
return File(qrCodeByteArr, "image/png");
```